# Передача значения в БД из <button>

Tags: php, javascript, база-данных

Как можно обработать значение кнопки, чтобы при выборе одной из трех кнопок данные записывались в разные таблицы?

Есть такая форма:

```
<form method="POST" action="/new">
  <button type="button" name="name_1">Название_1</button>
  <button type="button" name="name_2">Название_2</button>
  <button type="button" name="name_3">Название_3</button>
  <select name="name_4">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="name_5">
  <button type="submit" value="save" name="submit">Сохранить</button>
</form>
```

Я думал, что можно все решить при помощи php, но мне говорят, что тут что-то из js нужно.

Comment: А вы уверены, что вам нужно именно три _кнопки_, а не три radiobutton'а (или чего-то еще)?

Comment: Без обработки на php никак

Comment: То, что без php никак, я это прекрасно понимаю. А кнопки использую из-за дизайна. Радиокнопки тяжело кастомизировать, но можно попробовать поиграться с label...

Comment: То есть вы хотите этими кнопками имитировать радиокнопки?

Comment: Нашел решение. Спасибо Dmitriy Simushev за подсказку. Использовал radiobutton. Скрыл input и поигрался с label, в итоге получил то что хотел.